# How to Translate this sql to Linq (complicate SUM)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

This are the Tables

```cs
public class Purchase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string WareName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime BuyTime { get; set; }
    public IList<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
 }
public class Inventory
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    public long PurchaseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PurchaseId))]
    public Purchase Purchase { get; set; }

    public int SaledCount { get; set; }

}
```

I try to do a Query like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(x.[icout]) AS icount FROM
(
    SELECT p.[Count] - ISNULL(
            (SELECT SUM(i.SaledCount) FROM Inventory AS i WHERE i.PurchaseId = p.Id )
            ,0) AS [icout]
    FROM Purchase AS p 
    WHERE p.WareName ='WareName5' AND
    (  
        p.[Count] - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(i.SaledCount) FROM Inventory AS i WHERE i.PurchaseId = p.Id ),0) > 0
    )
) AS x`
```

```cs
var left = _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p=>p.Inventory)
            .Where(p=>p.WareName == WareName)
            .Select(p => p.Count - p.Inventory.Sum(i => i.SaledCount)).Sum();
```

But it doesn't work when I target a real database (sqlite / sqlserver).
And it works fine when I use inMemoryDatabase.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think you are missing DBCONTEXT which connects entity framework to Actual Database.

Comment: You are checking ISNULL in your SQL query and not checking in LINQ. Maybe you've got some NULLs in real DB so the sum is getting NULL too?

`var left = _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p=>p.Inventory)
            .Where(p=>p.WareName == WareName)
            .Select(p => p.Count - (p.Inventory.Sum(i => i.SaledCount) ?? 0)).Sum();`

Comment: @SagarR I'am very sure i am not missing DbContext

Comment: @Julia  `p.Inventory.sum()` return  `int` , and it can not use `??` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is just an attempt with the use of `let`, just tried it on my DNet Core site, and it ran nicely (I don't have the same entities as you do of course).

```
var left = from purchase in _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p=>p.Inventory)
           where purchase != null && purchase.WareName == WareName
           let sum = purchase.Inventory.Sum(i => i.SaledCount ?? 0)
           select (purchase.Count - sum).Sum();'
```

Here is a straight forward solution that should not be giving you a N+1 problem.
It solves the "complex" solution in-memory. sometimes the cost has to be somewhere, and in memory sum is better than N+1

```
var left = (from purchase in _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p=>p.Inventory)
           where purchase != null && purchase.WareName == WareName
           select new ()
           {
               count = purchase.Count - sum,
               invCounts = purchase.Inventory.where(a=> a.SaledCount!= null).Select(a=> a.SaledCount);
           }).ToList().Select(a => a.count - invCounts.Sum());
```

**Note**
Use `ICollection` instead of `IList` as it's features translates better to SQL
Also in the constructor initialize the collections to a `new HashSet<T>()` so you don't end up with a null exception. Think of it like this, you cannot count the element of `null` but you can count the elements of a collection with 0 rows.

```
public class Purchase
{
   public Purchase(){
      Inventory = new HashSet<Inventory>();
   }
   public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I try to use your solution with a little edit `var left = (from p in _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p => p.Inventory)
                        let sum = (p.Inventory.Sum(i =>i.SaledCount))
                        where p != null && p.WareName == WareName
                        select (p.Count - sum)).Sum();`  and it work, but it generate N+1 sql,

Comment: Added a different solution, that should get around the N+1 problem. the fall-back is that it solves the end solution in-memory. Id wish that your first query worked. But atleast now you have 2 workarounds (each with its  own drawbacks)

Comment: thanks, but your second solution doesn't solve the N+1 problem !, now i decide use this code `var left = (from p in _Db.Set<Purchase>().Include(p=>p.Inventory)
                        where p.WareName == WareName &&
                        (p.Inventory.Select(i=>((int?)i.SaledCount)).Sum()??0) < p.Count
                        select p).ToList().Sum(p => p.Count - p.Inventory.Sum(i => i.SaledCount));` .   it's very odd ,it will throw a Exception  when i'm not use `ToList()`.  ` Sequence contains more than one element`

Comment: when you use `ToList` you then perform the query and the result is now in memory of your application. And no more SQL work will be done in that query.